# How to remove sort from specific column in ui grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sorting, ui-grid

I have following code which is working fine for not having filters. Also able to set width even if it is a resizable grid. But sort is the only problem. Not able to remove the sort option from Edit column data. `sortable: false` is not working in my code. I can still the sort icon of arrow present in the row Header.

You can find the same in the screenshot. How to get rid off this?

```
                        let colDefs = [];
                        let editCol = {
                            name: 'test',
                            displayName: 'Edit',
                            cellTemplate: '<span class="glyphicons glyphicon-pencil edit-app-host"></span>',
                            width: '75',
                            enableFiltering: false,
                            sortable: false,
                            enableColumnMenu: false
                        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow was hidden with the help of css:

```
span i.ui-grid-icon-up-dir:first-child{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `enableSorting: false` on the column you don't want to be sortable and use `enableColumnMenu: false` on a column if you want to hide the menu arrow.
Example PLUNKER:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0FE4JSzVxPjduYQTA3ts?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but still i can see the arrow icon

Comment: Then you'll probably need to provide some more code, since the problem with your column config is that you're using `sortable: false`

Comment: set your initial colDef enableSorting: false and then set true for each individual columns if needed. But @DGarvanski code works, it's how I build my UI-grids. I have had issues before where the grid acted funky from time to time.